# Mentally-linked clones soldier pairs fight wars and nearly destroy the Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel, clones

This was a trilogy about a future earth where double clones were made to fight wars and they nearly destroyed the earth. They were good fighters because they were mentally linked. All were supposedly destroyed but a few were found by this reporter type.

I believe the USA version were called Jeeks.

In the second book a space ship containing a bunch of them returned.

In the final book one clone of a command 3 person clone fought them (the other 2 in the triad were killed and somehow this one did not go insane).

I have looked for this book for 30 years.

Answer (score 7):

I remember this. There was a trilogy called the *[Paratwa Saga](https://www.goodreads.com/series/57787-paratwa-saga)* by Christopher Hinz. The books were called *Liege-Killer*, *Ash Ock*, and *The Paratwa*.
Hinz also wrote a comic series in the 90s called *[Gemini Blood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_Blood)*, which lasted nine issues and took place in the Paratwa universe.

Comment: Great series, shame theres not more. Though the author did bring out a graphic novel of the first book a couple of years ago and included a short story set in the early years of the Paratwa

Comment: There were sequels to Liege Killer!?! Excellent!

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been scanning the books for years looking for this having forgot the Author and titles.Just ordered from Amazon.