# Book series about pairs of clones, Pratwa, that were mentally linked

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi, clones

There was a great sci-fi book series that I read about experiments with clones (Pratwa?). The lab produced sets of 2 clones that were linked mentally. When they meditated and merged consciousnesses they became a higher being, 2 minds became 1 new different personality.

They all had different weapons... the first attack was done by smiler/slasher clones. There was a scientist/researcher clone for tech.

When merged the sets of clones (5?) merged they met as Ash Oak.

The security team revived an old Pratwa hunter... he later turned out to be a Pratwa who's twin had been killed.

Does anyone know the name of book series?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are [the Paratwa novels](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/h/christopher-hinz/paratwa-saga-books-1-3.htm) by Christopher Hinz:

> In Christopher Hinz’s award-winning, postapocalyptic sci-fi trilogy, the Paratwa are genetically modified assassins who occupy two bodies telepathically connected and controlled by a single vicious mind. Humanity’s only hope for survival is to defeat these seemingly unstoppable warriors.

These have been previously identified in the question [Mentally-linked clones soldier pairs fight wars and nearly destroy the Earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84593/mentally-linked-clones-soldier-pairs-fight-wars-and-nearly-destroy-the-earth)

I'm guessing you read the first book [Liege-Killer](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/589852.Liege_Killer). The other two books are *Ash Ock* and *The Paratwa*.